# PySpark classes not found in Intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, apache-spark, pyspark

I have added `PYTHONPATH` with the path to the Spark libraries in an IntelliJ project:

[image]

However the PySpark classes are not accessible:

[image]
[image]

So what further needs to be done to the IJ project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add PySpark libraries to your project path as well. Assuming you're using IDEA  Intellij, not PyCharm go to <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> -> <kbd>SDKs</kbd> and configure Classpath for Python interpreter.

Comment: This is a mixed project with scala, java, and python: i tried what you said once in the past - thus changing from a java sdk to python. The  project got corrupted and I had to rebuild it.  Do you have comment on how to work with the mixed languages project?

Comment: It appears that I should create a separate python-only module. I'll upvote for kind of pointing the general direction

Comment: Separate project would be my personal preference (especially with PyCharm which works much better than IDEA) but if you use modules in your project you can define module specific SDK.

Comment: A year later and I can not reproduce the steps to make this work. Have you tried recently?  In particular I had tried adding `pyspark.zip` and `py4j.<version>.jar` but get `Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number`

Comment: I don't use intelij on daily basis but as far as I remember I used PySpark source root (`$SPARK_HOME/python`). Though gateway exit may suggest some other problem. If you don't resolve it ping me with the details (Spark version, Python version, InteliJ version).

Comment: I'll make another question - you'll deserve getting the points.

Comment: I checked, and it still works for me (Spark 2.1, IDEA 2016.3.4).